# MKLocalSearch in Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

Currently i am trying to use MKLocalSearch to show the informations around user, but the problem is that there is always fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I've tried to make sure that there is no optional value, but still got the error

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapKitViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var MapAround: MKMapView!
let locationManger:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
    var viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: MapAround.userLocation.location.coordinate, span: span)

    var request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "restaurants"
    request.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: MapAround.userLocation.location.coordinate, span: span)

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.startWithCompletionHandler {
        (response:MKLocalSearchResponse!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            println("searched")
            for item in response.mapItems as [MKMapItem]{
                println("Item name = \(item.name)")
            }
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
    var viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: MapAround.userLocation.location.coordinate, span: span)
    MapAround.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)

}
}
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You have two implicitly unwrapped optionals, the `MKMapView` and the `userLocation`. You might want to check to see if either of these are `nil`. The map view shouldn't be `nil` unless the the outlet was not hooked up properly or the view controller was not instantiated properly. The `userLocation` could conceivably be `nil` if location services had not yet determined the user's location.

As a general rule, when you first start location services (either through the map's "show user location" feature, or manually starting location services), it takes a little time before the user location is actually determined. As a result, one should be wary of ever trying to use the location directly in `viewDidLoad`.

Instead, you should implement the [`MKMapViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) method `didUpdateUserLocation` (and don't forget to set the `delegate` of the map view). That function will be called when the user location has been updated, and you should refrain from trying to use the location until that point.

Alternatively, you can start location services of your `CLLocationManager` and wait for `didUpdateLocations` (one of the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) methods). But the concept is the same: Recognize that determining the user's location happens asynchronously, so wait for the OS to tell you that it determined the user location (and one of sufficient accuracy for the purposes of your app).

Having said that, I'd actually be more inclined to implement this search as part of the map view's `regionDidChangeAnimated`. You probably want to search the visible map, rather than the user's current location. If you happen to be using `userTrackingMode` of `.Follow`, it's equivalent, but if you ever contemplate letting the user move the map around (e.g. let the user search where they're going rather than where they current are), the `regionDidChangeAnimated` probably makes more sense.